# Filter data.frame based on rowwise NA count

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to filter a `data.frame` based on the number of NA's in each row.

If I start with the following,

```
> d
  A   B   C   E
1 2   2   6   7
2 4   9  NA  10
3 6  NA  NA   4
4 9   7   1   8
```

I would like to filter `d` to remove rows with 2 or more NA's in columns A, B, and C to yield:

```
  A   B   C   E
1 2   2   6   7
2 4   9  NA  10
4 9   7   1   8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reproducibility, define a `data.frame` as below with various numbers of `NA`s in each row.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3, NA),
  B = c(1, 2, NA, NA),
  C = c(1, NA, NA, NA),
  E = c(5, 6, 7, 8)
)
```

Define a function that counts the number if `NA`'s in a given row:

```r
countNA <- function(df) apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) length(x[is.na(x)]))
```

Based on the wording of the question, exclude column `E` from this calculation:

```r
df_noE <- subset(df, select=-E)
```

Now count `NA`s in each row using the function above:

```r
na_count <- countNA(df_noE)
```

Now filter the original `data.frame` with this count:

```r
df[na_count < 2,]
```

**All together in a single line:**

```r
df[countNA(subset(df, select=-E)) < 2,]
```

Comment: Thank you Saladi!!! To clarify, if I want to scale this up to perform on each data frame inside my list of data frames, would I replace df with my df[i] ?

Comment: If `df` is actually a list of data frames, I think you'd want `df[[i]]`

Comment: Thank you very much @saladi - I posted my new question over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835597/in-r-use-a-function-apply-inside-of-lapply-that-is-working-over-a-list-of-dat

Answer (score 3):

We could use `rowSums` with `is.na` on the subset of columns of dataset to subset the rows

```
d[rowSums(is.na(d[1:3]))<2,]
#  A B  C  E
#1 2 2  6  7
#2 4 9 NA 10
#4 9 7  1  8
```

The `d[1:3]` select the dataset with only 'A, B, C' columns.  Applying `is.na` converts it to a logical matrix of `TRUE/FALSE`, do the `sum` of the TRUE values in each row with `rowSums`, and finally check if that number is less than 2 to get a logical `vector` which we use for subsetting the rows.

---

An alternative would be to use `Reduce` with `+`

```
d[Reduce(`+`,lapply(d[1:3], is.na)) <2,]
```