# In R, use a function apply() inside of lapply that is working over a list of data frames

Tags: r

I am using a function [from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834739/filter-data-frame-based-on-rowwise-na-count), that I want to run over every `data.frame` in my `list`. I can't seem to set up the indexing correctly, and after [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659918/r-passing-the-index-of-the-corresponding-data-frame-from-a-list-of-data-frames) thought maybe I needed to leave the function outside of my original `lapply`, but that didn't improve anything.

My two data frames with NAs turned into a list:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3, NA),
  B = c(1, 2, NA, NA),
  C = c(1, NA, NA, NA),
  E = c(5, 6, 7, 8)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3, NA),
  B = c(1, 2, NA, NA),
  C = c(1, NA, NA, NA),
  E = c(5, 6, 7, 8)
)

mylist <- list(df1, df2)
```

My function inside of the lapply:

```
dd <- lapply(seq_along(mylist), function(i){

        countNA <- function(mylist[[i]]) apply(mylist[[i]], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) length(x[is.na(x)]))

        df_mos <- subset(mylist[[i]], select = c("A", "B", "C"))

         na_count <- countNA(df_mos)

         x = mylist[[i]][na_count < 2,]

         x = x[, c("E")] # Only give me value of E 

         x # return x 
        })
```

For which I would expect the following:

```
> dd
[[1]]
   E
1  5
2  6

[[2]]
   E
1  5
2  6
```

R gives me this error beginning with the bracket (and I've already tried using only one bracket instead of two, but the same thing occurs):

```
> dd <- lapply(seq_along(mylist), function(i){
+         
+         countNA <- function(mylist[i]) apply(mylist[i], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) length(x[is.na(x)]))
Error: unexpected '[' in:
"        
        countNA <- function(mylist["
>         
>         df_mos <- subset(mylist[i], select = c("A", "B", "C"))
Error in subset(mylist[i], select = c("A", "B", "C")) : 
  object 'i' not found
>         
>          na_count <- countNA(df_mos)
Error: could not find function "countNA"
>          
>          x = mylist[i][na_count < 2,]
Error: object 'i' not found
>          
>          x = x[, c("E")] # Only give me value of E 
Error: object 'x' not found
>          
>          x # return x 
Error: object 'x' not found
>         })
Error: unexpected '}' in "        }"
```

Comment: `lapply(mylist, function(x) x[rowSums(is.na(x))<2,][['E']])` ?

Comment: @jeremycg, i'm not sure what you're referring to?

Comment: @ jeremycg I cannot just use mylist, for the rowsums because I am only trying to get the sum out of a subset of columns (my real data has 20+ variables, and I need 8 out of 12 to have values in order to return what is being called "E" in this example)

Comment: Building on jeremycg's comment, you could replace all of your code with `dd <- lapply(mylist, function(x) x[rowSums(is.na(x[,c("A","B","C")]))<2, "E", drop=FALSE])` . This gives the value of `dd` that you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `countNA` function to this:

```
countNA <- function(list_entry) apply(list_entry, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) length(x[is.na(x)]))
```

As it is, you are taking a specific subsetted list as an argument, whereas a function should take a general argument, in your case a list. How that list is being isolated in order to pass into that function is handled elsewhere.